# vscode issue, python extension loading forever

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]

I could not delete/reinstall `vsCode` and `python`. I think `GitHub` has a solution, but I don't know how to solve it. I want to know the solution and how to roll back vs. Code.

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/14977

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/3967

Comment: add a comment to issue 14977 if you still have the problem. Issue 3967 is over a year old and not likely to be relevant